# 'gargle_oauth_cache' command from googlesheets4, R package

Tags: r, google-sheets, token, shinyapps, googlesheets4

I'm new to using the 'googlesheets4' package, from R, so I'm not able to use it in a shiny project.

I can use the app locally, however when I put it on the web an error appears.

From the research I've done, it seems to me that it has something to do with the command:

```
options( gargle_oauth_email = ,
  gargle_oauth_cache =
)
```

however I don't know what to put in `gargle_oauth_cache`. Where should this information be obtained? Where can I find it?

Comment: Is it `gargle_oauth_email`or `google_oauth_email` ?

Comment: In the link I read it said 'gargle_oauth_cache'

Post: [link](https://www.jdtrat.com/blog/connect-shiny-google/)